# How to select objects that match a certain pattern in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, duplicates, conditional-statements

So for an excel csv file, I'm trying to get rid of all duplicate cd numbers that have a empty cell in the AD column when at least one of the cd numbers has a cell in the AD column that is not empty (values are hi, me,too), so it should look like this.

But I don't want to delete duplicate cd numbers that have in their ADs one of these ( hi, me,too) and I dont want to delete single cd number whether it has an empty cell in the AD column or has (hi, me,too) in the AD as the value.

This is what I tried out as my script:

```
$GroupArray2 = @(
    'hi'
    'me'
    'to'
)
$items4 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Excel6.csv' | Group-object -Property 'AD' | Where-Object count -gt 1 | Where-object {$_.'AD' -in $GroupArray2} | Foreach-object { $selections3 = $_.Group | Select-Object -Property * }
$items4 | Export-CSv -path 'C:\Temp\Excel7.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

But it won't output anything when I try it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly this should work

```
$GroupArray2 = 'hi','me','too'

$result = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Excel6.csv' | Group-object -Property 'CD' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Count -gt 1) {
        # we've found multiple rows with same cd
        # get the items that have their AD set to one in the $GroupArray2 array
        $assigned = $_.Group | Where-object {$_.'AD' -in $GroupArray2}
        # get the items that have their AD set to nothing
        $notAssigned = $_.Group | Where-object {[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'AD')}
        # if we have both, return only the $assigned items, otherwise the entire group
        if (($assigned) -and ($notAssigned)) { $assigned } else { $_.Group }
    }
    else { 
        # single item, return whether is has an AD or not
        $_.Group
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\Excel7.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate the objects by groups before checking where `$_.'AD' -in $GroupArray2`

```
$items4 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Excel6.csv' | Group-object -Property 'CD' | Where-Object count -gt 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.group}  | Where-object {$_.'AD' -in $GroupArray2}
```

Also note what kind of delimiter you use. Your sample csv contained commas as part of the string and it's the default delimiter, too. Use the `-Delimiter` parameter of `Import-/Export-Csv` to use an other symbol:

```
$items4 = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ";" | Group-object -Property 'CD' | Where-Object count -gt 1 | ForEach-Object {$_.group}  | Where-object {$_.'AD' -in $GroupArray2} 
$items4 | Export-CSv -path 'C:\Temp\Excel7.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```